# Getting a better lock screen

Tags: lock-screen

Why is it I can configure my login screen to look like this (using a script to set the gdm background that seems to break and have a new version for each version of Ubuntu?!?):
[image: with an image spanning both monitors and a nice little login dialog]

But all I can get out of Ubuntu is something on one screen that looks like a kid took a crayon to my screen:

[image]

Are there better alternatives to a lock screen that will span both monitors, easily allow say random, nice-looking backgrounds, and the ability to add some things to the lock screen like the next appointment, emails, text messages, etc? We have this for phones, so why not for desktops?

I'm currently on Ubuntu 22.04 and use XScreenSaver as my screen saver ('cause it's cool) under a Mate environment but would consider switching to something else if it was better. As it is I rarely lock my system as 1) I live alone and 2) the current lock screen sucks!